# Getting value of foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

```
class Sample(models.model):
sampleID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    something = models.IntegerField()
    .
    .
    .

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_new = self.pk is None
    super(Sample, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_new:
        alpha = AnotherSample()
        alpha.asampleID =  self.pk
        alpha.say = "Lolz"
        alpha.save()
```

I cannot assign my primary key to the AnotherSample's referencing key for Sample. It always say

```
Cannot assign "1L": "AnotherSample.asampleID" must be a "Sample" instance.
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation):

> Behind the scenes, Django appends `"_id"` to the field name to create its database column name.

```
alpha.asampleID_id = self.pk
```

This is why having a suffix of "ID" is inappropriate.

Comment: @danihp: Sure. But that doesn't mean that there's a `Sample` with that PK.

Answer (score 0):

From the given error message, it looks like you are trying to save a relationship. You should pass the actual object, not its primary key.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_new = self.pk is None
    super(Sample, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_new:
        alpha = AnotherSample()
        alpha.asampleID =  self
        alpha.say = "Lolz"
        alpha.save()
```